# Determine for which pairs $\eta, \lambda > 0$ the mappings $h_\eta, h_\lambda$ are conjugate in $\text{Mob}(\mathbb{H)}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, algebraic-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, mobius-transformation

I have (what I believe to be) a *partial proof* of the problem below. I do not; however, know how to treat the $\eta = 1, \lambda \neq 1$ case.

For any $\eta > 0$ let

\begin{equation}
h_\eta(z) = - \eta \overline{z}.
\end{equation}

Determine for which pairs $\eta, \lambda > 0$ the mappings $h_\eta, h_\lambda$ are conjugate in $\text{Mob}(\mathbb{H)}$.

*Partial proof:* Suppose that the mappings $h_\eta, h_\lambda$ are conjugate in $\text{Mob}(\mathbb{H})$. It follows that:

\begin{equation}
\tau(h_\eta) = \tau(h_\lambda).
\end{equation}

Hence (w.l.o.g.),

\begin{equation}
\eta + \frac{1}{\eta} + 2 = \lambda + \frac{1}{\lambda} + 2.
\end{equation}

Therefore, either $\eta = \lambda$, or $\eta = \frac{1}{\lambda}$.

For your reference:

$\tau(f)$ denotes the squared trace of $f \in \text{Mob}(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.